# Send a simple notification email to myself with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, automation

I have a Laravel web app where I'd like to be notified when users take a certain rare action. I've already set up logging for this, but logs are written quietly to a file and I'd like something that notifies me to check the logs - ideally an automated email that I can trigger within the app to go to my Zoho-hosted email (so Outlook/Gmail spam filters shouldn't be a problem). The problem is that Laravel doesn't seem to have any simple way to send a quick plain-text email on the fly, without creating a [whole class, view](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#generating-mailables) and possibly controller to go with it.

Is this really not possible, or am I missing something? The web app is hosted on a DigitalOcean droplet so setting it up for something like `sendmail` shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Mail::raw`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Mail.html#method_raw) to send a plain, classless/viewless message.

```
Mail::raw('Hello world', function (Message $message) {
    $message->to('example@gmail.com')
        ->from('example@example.com');
});
```

If you want a more complicated email, you might consider [`Mail::plain`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Mail.html#method_plain), which will accept a view, bindings, but doesn't need a Mailable class.

Personally, though, I prefer a real mailable for any programmatic email, even if it's rare. There's no downside to having class/views for it; they're only loaded if necessary, and having them in the mail folders makes it much clearer what mails your app might possibly send.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, how did you find this? It's not anywhere in the documentation. Also appreciate the extra perspective, I wanted a quick and dirty way to get something done but it's possible setting up a Mailable class is less complicated than it seems so I may just opt for that in the end.

Comment: @HashimAziz The hand-written documentation (correctly, IMO) covers only the more common use cases; I know this exists because I've had to go digging in the full automated API docs before. Try a real Mailable first, though; `php artisan make:mail` will get you like 90% of the way there.

Comment: I had no idea the API documentation was a thing, will have to make a mental note to consult it from now on.